# Comments cache: how to delete with wordpress preview post?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, comments

In my website I use the Facebook comments plugin, and if I want a post preview with WordPress, Facebook run cache page. In this way, when a post is published, the Facebook cache don't see post title, description, image, etc., and it fix only if a go here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Is there a solution to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the debug link worked. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

After running the debug link, it pointed to some errors and missing og:description data.

I then added the following line  into the header of my wordpress site. Voila! Ran the debug again, then went back to my Facebook and posted my link
http://petition.joelfrenette.com and it does now correctly grab the cached values, img, title, description, etc...

Thanks for your guidance, Joel